# How do I escape a backtick in a JavaScript raw string?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, escaping, template-literals

I have a raw string (created with the `String.raw` method and template literal), which is supposed to contain several backslashes and backticks. Since the backticks are required to be escaped even in a raw string, I use backward slashes to escape them. Although, it does escape the backtick, the backward slash is also displayed along with it:

```js
let rawString = String.raw`
  __    
 /  |   
 \`| |   
  | |   
 _| |_  
|_____| 


`;

console.log(rawString);
```

- How do I escape the backtick such that there is no extra backward slash preceding it?

---

#### Some Clarifications

- The string is **required** to be a raw string.
- The backticks are necessary. They can't be replaced with single quotes or anything like that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<sub>So, while writing the question, I came up with an idea myself, and to my utmost surprise - it works!</sub>

---

Instead of using the backward slash for escaping, use `${...}` (["placeholder" for string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)); like this:

```js
let rawString = String.raw`
  __    
 /  |   
 ${"`"}| |   
  | |   
 _| |_  
|_____| 


`;

console.log(rawString);
```

Comment: That's brilliant. Obvious once you see it, but kudos for coming up with that solution.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var v='`';
let rawString = String.raw`
      __    
     /  |   
     `+v+`| |
      | |   
     _| |_  
    |_____| 


`;

//From seeing from your idea, you can join it like below:

console.log(rawString);
rawString = String.raw`
      __    
     /  |   
     ${v}| |
      | |   
     _| |_  
    |_____| 


`;

console.log(rawString);
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question because I have very clearly stated in the question that the raw string contains several backticks.

Comment: I suggest you delete your answer or update it to comply with the question. Thank you for trying to help though!

Comment: I have updated this, the other answer will be a lot cleaner, which was also yours